# Screen was frozen after coming back from fullscreen

Tags: 16.04, unity, graphics, intel-graphics, gui

When I watched a Youtube video in fullscreen it worked fine, but when I turned back from fullscreen to normal, the screen was frozen and I was unable to type anything from my keyboard. I restarted my machine to escape this issue. However, when I see video from videos app or vlc on fullscreen and come back, nothing froze.

I searched, and found some things relating to Chrome or flash, but I found nothing that helped me.

My current system is Ubuntu 16.04, Intel® Core™ i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4, 8GB Ram, and Intel HD 4000.

**EDIT** The issue happened when I upgraded OpenGL & Mesa. I tried downgrading but the issue wasn't gone. So I must reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: No, not resolve my issue,  so that I must reinstall Ubuntu to pass this bug.

Comment: Then what is your issue and your question? What are you trying to achieve? Please [edit] your question to clarify that. Thanks.